# Do visual glitches affect the way you fish?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Often when using my indoor pool, I have to aim my rod quite shallow (so it doesn't hit the other end of the pool), and as a result my bob often floats above the water (i.e. it isn't in the water but floats about one block above it). Does having the bob float outside the water (in what appears to be a visual glitch) affect your ability to fish or is it simply just a client-side visual glitch?

In addition, would fishing so my rod hits the edge of the indoor pool after being cast (not landing on but sliding across the water so it hits the side) also affect my ability to fish?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing), depth nor position of the bobber or player affect fishing in any way. Fishing works the way it should in any depth of water.

Answer (score 0):

If the bob floats in, or above water, your chance for getting the fish are the same. Enchantments change these, but otherwise chance for the fish to spawn are the same Actually, large open pools may take longer as the fish takes time to get to the hook after getting spawned, while a single block of water has the fish spawn and bite at the same moment - but time between casting the line and fish spawning is unchanged.

Two things may be affected:

- the fish/loot once you start reeling in: It spawns as an entity at the bob and flies the player, but with objects in the way, hoppers and the likes, it may collide.
- wear of the fishing rod. If the hook lands in water, no problem, same 1 point of wear when fish is caught, 0 if reeled in empty. But if it lands on a solid block, reeling it in costs 2 points of durability. (just switch to a different item instead, that way no durability is lost.)/sky

Also: water with no sky access spawns fish half as frequently, so if your pool is *indoor* that's the reason you're getting your rate halved.